# "Sparse" Theta Series

Tags: coding-theory, theta-functions, euclidean-lattices, theta-series

The number of integer points with a given norm in the integer grid $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ may be calculated via the generating function
$$\theta_3(q)^2= \left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2}\right)^2 = 1+4 q + 4 q^2 + 4 q^4 + 8 q^5 + \cdots,$$ 
which is a so called (squared) Jacobi function. Similarly the generating function for the shifted $(\mathbb{Z}+a)\times(\mathbb{Z}+b)$ is given by (say $\Theta(a,b)$)
$$\Theta(a,b)=\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{(n+a)^2}\right)\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{(n+b)^2}\right)$$ 
which can also be written as a function as Jacobi function of two variables.

For example, if $(a,b)=(\sqrt{2}/3,3/10)$, we have

$$\Theta(a,b) \approx q^{1.91222}+q^{0.769413}+q^{0.712222}+q^{0.369413}+q^{0.312222}$$

My question is if the following problem (or anything related) has been studied: what is the value of (a,b) that makes
(i) all coefficients in the expansion of $\Theta(a,b)$ equal to one and (ii) the **difference between successive exponents** in $\Theta(a,b)$ the largest possible.

Comment: What is the "difference between successive exponents"? Which ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't the following argument show that the difference between successive exponents can never be bounded away from zero no matter how clever you try to be in selecting $(a,b)$?

The idea is to consider pairs of integers $(n,m)$ such that $na-mb$ is close to zero.

1. If the ratio $a/b$ is rational then we can find integers $n,m$ such that $na=mb$. But in that case
   $$(n+a)^2+(-m+b)^2=n^2+m^2+a^2+b^2+2(na-mb)=n^2+m^2+a^2+b^2$$
   and also
   $$
   (-n+a)^2+(m+b)^2=\cdots=n^2+m^2+a^2+b^2
   $$
   meaning that the theta series has coefficients $>1$.
2. On the other hand if the ratio $a/b$ is irrational then, to a given $\epsilon>0$, we can find integers $n,m$ such that
   $$
   |na-mb|<\epsilon.
   $$
   This is because the additive group generated by $a$ and $b$ is then a dense subset of $\Bbb{R}$. But, reusing the above points, we see that
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   ||(n+a,-m+b)||^2-||(-n+a,m+b)||^2&=(n^2+m^2+a^2+b^2)+2(na-mb)\\
   &-(n^2+m^2+a^2+b^2)+2(na-mb)\\
   &=4(na-mb),
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   which is $<4\epsilon$.

A geometrical motivation for finding these points came from the observation that when $\pm(n,-m)$ is nearly orthogonal to $(a,b)$, we are bound to get two points yielding nearly equal exponents of $q$.

Comment: Very true, I think I was overly optimistic to find a lower bound for the ``infinite'' lattice. The problem would only make sense for a finite (e.g. inside a cube) subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @Campello. Unfortunately that is the case. It looks like you will have to contend with optimizing how quickly the differences between the exponents go to zero as the range of $n,m$ increases. Not entirely unlike in [my past question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/98278/15503).

Comment: Yes, my question was clearly not well formulated... :P Thanks for the answer !